# how to delete all duplicate rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, join, sql-delete

this is my table `role_users` for particular id
[image]

I want to delete all duplicate rows for role_id and user_id and if 2 or more records are there then only 1 latest record should be there and other should be deleted. How can i write this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `delete ... from ... join...` syntax:

```
delete r
from role_users r
inner join (
    select role_id, user_id, max(id) max_id
    from role_users
    group by role_id, user_id
) r1 
    on r.role_id = r1.role_id 
    and r.user_id = r1.user_id
    and r.id < r1.max_id
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'r1.created_at' in 'on clause'

Comment: i checked with this query select role_id,user_id,count(1) from role_users group by role_id,user_id   and got repeated rows

Comment: @aashu1807 try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63825910/5466534

Comment: @aashu1807: if so, it means that you have duplicated values in `created_at` for the same `(role_id, user_id)`.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: @aashu1807: how do you define the *latest record*?

Comment: let us forgot about latest record. I just want to delete duplicate entries for role_id and user_id and keep only 1 record

Comment: @aashu1807: I changed the query to use the `id` instead of `created_at`.

Comment: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

The following query would give you IDs of all Unique records grouped by role_id & user_id

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM role_users GROUP BY role_id, user_id
```

Notice the MAX function here to get the latest created record assuming id is auto_increment

Use it in a nested query to delete all the other duplicate records

```
DELETE FROM role_users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM role_users GROUP BY role_id, user_id);
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: this query giving me no response. throwing error Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction